# Refreshing existing nodes to pick up Automatic Nodetitles in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, token

I have a set of existing nodes for a content type ('foo'). Since then I have installed the Automatic Nodetitles module, which has helped tremendously, since I no longer need to work hard to make standardized names for each node of that type. I have used Automatic Nodetitles in conjunction with Tokens to create an automatic title naming pattern based on Node and CCK fields. This works perfectly for any new node I create of this content types?

How do I refresh existing nodes to pick up their titles with the "Automatic Nodetitles" Drupal 6 module?

Thanks,

Comment: Wow, the Pathauto module adds custom aliases too, and creating aliases for nodes without them is done with a single click in the settings... Dunno about Automatic Nodetitles though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)' built-in "List all content" replacement view (defaults to admin/content/node2), which will give you more flexibility in selecting/filtering nodes to update. VBO also allows you to select and perform an action on *all* nodes, rather than just a page at a time, like Drupal's default content listing.

Comment: I tried this out myself, and if you have hundreds of nodes you want to change, this does so more elegantly than the solution I found. Recommended. 

Note that VBO takes a little bit of work to get running. I found this quickstart guide to be highly helpful. http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations#quickstart6

Answer (score 4):

Had to do quite a bit of searching to find the solution, but I found it:
http://drupal.org/node/265773#comment-3055470

Specifically:

> "Updating nodetitles from existing
>   nodes
>
> ---
>
> If you set the nodetitle to be auto
>   generated for some content type,
>   existing nodes are not affected. You
>   can update existing nodes by going to
>   'admin/content/node', then filter for
>   your content type, mark some nodes and
>   choose the "Update option" "Update
>   automatic nodetitles"

Posted to SO for everyone's benefit. One of the "Update options" Is "update automatic nodetitles". I never would have guessed! No need for an additional module or function; it is already there (once Automatic Nodetitles is installed, of course).

Comment: I like to see when people do their own research instead of sitting around hoping someone else will give them an answer... +1

Answer (score 0):

Than only works well if you have a bunch of nodes, what if you have 5000?